# Detect if file is open in C++

Tags: c++, windows

Is there any way in C++ to detect if a file is already open in another program?.
I want to delete and rewrite some files, but in case a file is opened I want to display an error message. I am using Windows OS.

Comment: A similar question have been asked and answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691603/whats-a-programmatic-way-to-detect-if-a-file-is-opened-in-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Taking an action depending on the result of the "*is file open query*" is a race condition (the query returns `false` and then a program opens the file before your program attempts to delete it for example).

Attempt to delete the file using [`DeleteFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and if it fails display the reason the file delete failed, using [`GetLastError()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). See [System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the list of error codes (`ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` which states *"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."*)

Comment: Under what conditions can a file be opened by a program, if I don't open it myself? It is a little bit confusing to me. Can you please give me some examples?

Comment: @AlexandraC, I am unsure what you mean by "if I don't open it myself"? If a file exists any program can attempt to open it if it wants. An sensible example would be a virus checker, which can periodically open files to examine the content.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is very helpful. I wanted to know why would a program want to open a file. Is there any documentation where I can read more about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CreateFile API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the share mode of NULL, which opens the file for exclusive use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [remove("filename")](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/remove/) function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `is_open()` to check if the file is open. If it is you can close it or do somehting else.
Here is an exampe:

```
int main () 
{

  fstream filestr;
  filestr.open ("test.txt");

  if (filestr.is_open())
  {

   filestr << "File successfully open";
   filestr.close();

  }

  else
  {

   cout << "Error opening file";

  } 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: This would not check whether the file is open in other programs, only whether you succeeded in opening it for yourself.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

int main () {
  std::ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open ("example.txt");
  if (ofs.is_open())
  {
    ofs << "anything";
    std::cout << "operation successfully performed\n";
    ofs.close();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Error opening file";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...and then some other process opens the file between the `close` and your attempt to remove it...

Comment: @molbdnilo: I didn't understand exactly. Is it something about synchronization of accessing the file by two processes?

Comment: Yes, see the answer by hmjd. There is no point to your test since it can be made invalid at any time afterwards. (Assuming a preemptively multitasking OS.)