# Detecting if a file is open

Tags: c++, file, detection, file-exists

How can I detect if a file is open in C++?
I am trying to use a code like this:

```
    int main()
    {
        ifstream file("file.txt");
        if ( /*here comes the check if file is open*/ ) cout<<"File open successfully"; else cout<<"File couldn't be opened. Check if the file is not used by another program or if it exists";
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `file.is_open()`?

Comment: do you mean 'if (file.is_open) ...'?

Comment: No I mean `file.is_open()`, [std::istream::is_open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/)

Comment: It's possible that the desired checking of whether a file is open, can be accomplished via the `is_open` member function.

Comment: In some cases you don't need to explicitly check if a file is open, just do e.g. `while (file >> some_variable) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if file is open in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258277/detect-if-file-is-open-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the function *is_open()*

```
if(file.is_open()){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file.is_open())
```

You are calling `ifstream::is_open()` function