# How to detect if file is openned by other process in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm opening files using the `_findfirst` function in windows, but I will only want to open files which are not opened by other process. The situation is that I will scan a directory read the files and delete them while other process create new files in it.

To avoid race conditions I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691603/whats-a-programmatic-way-to-detect-if-a-file-is-opened-in-windows) which mentions the possibility to open a file with a `no sharing` option. But how is that done?

Update: I have no control about the writing process, so don't know which flags, if nay, are used when creating a file. Moreover the writing process may change (third party software).

Comment: open the file for write and catch the exception

Comment: If the file is open by another process then `DeleteFile` will simply fail, it shouldn't result in race condition. Unless the other process is creating the file with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag (which is unlikely). There is not enough information in your question...

Comment: @BarmakShemirani, I have updated my question, any more information that is required / useful?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your 2 processes are the only ones that will open the files then, from [MSDN open sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],                // name of the write
                       GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
                       0,                      // *** do not share ***
                       NULL,                   // default security
                       CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                       NULL);                  // no attr. template
```

By using this in your writing process you can then check for INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE in the reading process and in this case if GetLastError() returns ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION then you know that your file is opened by another process with no sharing.

More details can be found in the [CreateFile documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I have no control over the writing process, does this still holds?

Comment: Then depends if the writing process opens with no sharing... If you can make the writing process create a huge file then you could test this case... If not maybe IFileIsInUse could help. I've seen some threads talking about the IFileIsInUse interface from Windows Shell but I didn't find any good code sample and I've never used it...

Answer (score 1):

Call [OpenFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430(v=vs.85).aspx) and as `uStyle` (third param) add at least `OF_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE`.

Answer (score 1):

to open a file with no sharing option, you can use

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("somFileName",
                      GENERIC_WRITE,
                      0, /*no sharing; other options are FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_SHARE_WRITE etc*/
                      NULL,
                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                      NULL);
```